# Escape property in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven-2, launch4j

I would like to escape a property in pom.xml. Not in ressources, I know it is possible with a filter. For example I try to use launch4j plugin like this :

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.bluestemsoftware.open.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>launch4j-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>l4j-cli</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>launch4j</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <headerType>console</headerType>
                            <outfile>../out.exe</outfile>
                            <dontWrapJar>true</dontWrapJar>
                            <jar>./../out.jar</jar>
                            <icon>../icon.ico</icon>
                            <chdir>.</chdir>
                            <customProcName>true</customProcName>
                            <downloadUrl>http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html</downloadUrl>
                            <classPath>
                                <mainClass>com.stack.Main</mainClass>
                                <addDependencies>true</addDependencies>
                                <jarLocation>./lib</jarLocation>
                            </classPath>
                            <jre>
                                <opts>
                                    <opt>-DconfigBasePath=${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/dir</opt>
       </opts>                          
                            </jre>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And ${ALLUSERSPROFILE} must not be interpreted by maven but by the program generate by launch4j. 
I try :

```
\${ALLUSERSPROFILE}
\\${ALLUSERSPROFILE}
$${ALLUSERSPROFILE}
```

and

```
<properties>
   <dollar>$</dollar>
</properties>
${dollar}{ALLUSERSPROFILE}
```

but nothing work.

Comment: According to [this thread](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/escape-some-value-td122820.html), `$${ALLUSERSPROFILE}` should work.

Comment: I saw this thread but it doesn't work

Comment: Post a complete POM which works out of box and reproduce the bug.

Comment: \u0024  work for me

Answer (score 1):

`$$` worked for me with [`${surefire.forkNumber}`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkCount).

Answer (score 0):

I add the same issue when I wanted to filter my **log4j.properties** file by resolving the key **'${log4j.dir}'** with the pom property value **'${user.home}'**.

Neither $${key} hack nor ${dollar}{key} hack worked for me.
I finally managed to do it using the HEXA notation for the $ char in the pom property.

```
<project>
    <properties>
    <log4j.dir>\u0024{user.home}</log4j.dir>
    </properties>
    <!--...-->
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following slightly modified from the above thread worked for me:

```
    <properties> 
      <dollar>$</dollar> 
      <dollar.bloop>${dollar}{bloop}</dollar.bloop> 
    </properties>
```

- `$$` was not recognised by IntelliJ. I really want the editor to not
  have red squiggles.
- With `\u0024` the literal backslash was carried through, and at no point was replaced with $.

YMMV I suppose.

Comment: Neither with Maven 3.6.0

Comment: The only one that worked for me using Maven 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

For true escaping in a `pom.xml` you are out of luck.

Some answers above make reference to the Surefire plugin, which uses its own syntax for escaping.  That's not the same thing.

Maven resource filtering uses *its* own mechanism for escaping.  That's not the same thing.

If you merely need to print something, you can use the [zero-width-space unicode character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space), like this:

```
$&#8203;{somePomProperty}
```

This will be rendered as:

```
$ + zero-width-space + { + somePomProperty + }
```

and will at least look correct.